# LSTM same input and output number

Tags: python, lstm, layer

I'm trying to figure out how to model a LSTM model to predict two attributes from the same number of attributes. However, I cannot configure the layers correctly. Any help?  You have more information here. [Wrong output LSTM Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72817320/wrong-output-lstm-keras)

Comment: Is this question the same as the question you linked to?

Comment: yes. it is the same issue

Comment: so why post this question if it's the same? Sorry, I'll have to vote to close this as a duplicate then

Comment: @ForceBru do you have a clue about my issue?